# How to turn UTC times into local ("America/New_York") in r?

Tags: r, timezone

I am having trouble getting the correct results using other recommended solutions.

When I run

```
t
```

the result is this:

```
> t
[1] "2016-08-22 09:25:39 UTC"
```

but when I change to local time, it doesn't change the result

```
t  %>% as.POSIXct(tz = "America/New_York")
```

produces this...

```
> t  %>% as.POSIXct(tz = "America/New_York")
[1] "2016-08-22 09:25:39 UTC"
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get this to appropriately change the time?

Comment: try `Sys.setenv(tz = "America/New_York")`

Comment: `lubridate::with_tz(time = ymd_hms("2016-08-22 09:25:39 UTC"), tzone = "America/New_York")`